# Get foci of fabric.Ellipse

Tags: fabricjs

Using fabric.js, I want to draw an ellipse, then draw objects along the ellipse's circumference.

How can I get the foci of a fabric.Ellipse, in order to calculate the circumference? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the parametric equations for an ellipse are

```
x = a*cos(theta)
y = b*sin(theta)
```

where a and b are fabric.Ellipse rx and ry attributes. I presume you want the circumference in order to evenly space the objects on the ellipse. It'd be easier to simply divide 360 degrees into whatever fractions you want and plug into the above equations.

More fun equations for the ellipse may be found here: http://www.nabla.hr/Z_MemoHU-029.htm